# Not loading localized string using ResourceManager in DNX 4.5.1

Tags: c#, localization, visual-studio-2015, resourcemanager, dnx

I'm trying to add localization to my DNX 4.5.1 project in Visual studio 2015. I have two `resx` files..

```
Culture.resx
Culture.sv.resx
```

Both as embedded by setting `resource` in `project.json`

```
"resource": "**\\*.resx"
```

I create the `ResourceManager`.

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Core.Culture",
                         typeof(CultureManager).Assembly);
```

And try to get a localized string. This gives me the value from `Culture.resx` as expected.

```
var result = resourceManager.GetString("Test1");
```

If I however try to get the Swedish value I just continue getting the default value.

```
var result = resourceManager.GetString("Test1", new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
```

Is there some problem with the satellite assemblies being created for the non default languages?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue stated on github: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2161